# Solving a 2nd order, nonlinear ODE involving trigonometric terms using FDM

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I'm rather new to solving ODEs/PDEs numerically and am trying to solve a 2nd order, nonlinear ODE involving trigonometric terms using finite-differences.
The ODE has the followign form:
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = a \cdot \sin(y) + b \cdot \cos(y)
$$
I would like to numerically solve this in matrix operation form:
$$
A \cdot \vec{y} = \vec{b}
$$
Discretizing using the standard FDM-stencil:
$$
\frac{y_{i+1} - 2y_i + y_{i-1}}{\Delta x^2} = a \cdot \sin(y_i) + b \cdot \sin(y_i)
$$
But because of the trigonometric terms either $A$ or $\vec{b}$ must be dependent on $\vec{y}$. For example:
$$
\frac{1}{\Delta x^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2 & 1 & 0 &\cdots \\
& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \\
\cdots & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
y_{i-1} \\
y_i \\
y_{i+1} \\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a \cdot \sin(y_{i-1}) + b \cdot \sin(y_{i-1}) \\
a \cdot \sin(y_i) + b \cdot \sin(y_i) \\
a \cdot \sin(y_{i+1}) + b \cdot \sin(y_{i+1}) \\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The only solution I could think of is an iteration loop $j$, where I give a starting guess for $\vec{y}$ into $\vec{b}$ and then use $\vec{y}_j - \vec{y}_{j-1}$ as a residual to iterate.

What would be the best strategy to this problem? Is it possible to avoid iterating?

EDIT:
added the discretization I thought of

Comment: A few things. Is this an initial value problem? Finite-differences are best-suited to boundary value problems. An incorrect choice of boundary conditions can make this specific problem ill-posed. This is a nonlinear problem and the discretized system should reflect that. You should have a system of nonlinear equations for the coefficieint vector $\vec{y}$, whcih can be solved by Newton's method or something similar. Linearizing the problem is not what you want to do here.

Comment: @whpowell96 : It is indeed a BVP. Newtons Method would as well mean a outer iteration loop, but if the problem, as you said, cannot be properly solved using some form of linearization, it seems that i can't avoid iteration.

Comment: The problem is much simpler if you switch variables.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Could you further elaborate what you mean by switching?

Comment: Iterative methods are standard in numerical ODEs and PDEs. It is very rare that one actually solves even the linear systems directly instead of with an iterative method in practice.

Comment: @whpowell96 naturally, but as I was able to solve simpler problems without iteration I thought it might be possible to do this one without as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y'' = a \, \sin(y) + b \, \cos(y)$$ Switching variables
$$-\frac {x''}{[x']^3}= a \, \sin(y) + b \, \cos(y)$$ Reduction of order $p=x'$
$$ -\frac {p'}{p^3}= a \, \sin(y) + b \, \cos(y)$$
Integration
$$p=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 (b \sin (y)-a \cos (y))+c_1}}=x'$$
Integrate again and you have an explicit solution for $x(y)$ which is impossibel to inverse.

But, numerically, staying with $p=x'$, you face a first order equation.